# how to make apache hosted website url requests case insensitive

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have my page1.php file located inside

`/public_html/mypages/page1.php`

if user requests `www.myurl.com/Mypages/Page1.php`  is returning `file not found`

how can I ensure that each each request is handled irrespective of the case

I am using godaddy linux server

from their support page

https://support.godaddy.com/help/article/899/how-do-i-use-mod_rewrite

I came to know that it can be done from `.htaccess`

so I added a `.htaccess` to `/public_html/mypages/`

http://www.chrisabernethy.com/force-lower-case-urls-with-mod_rewrite/

here is the content of my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteMap  lc int:tolower
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
RewriteRule (.*) ${lc:$1} [R=301,L]
```

after this when I try to access  any file `www.myurl.com/Mypages/Page1.php` its giving internal server error. Please help me resolve this issue .

I also tried adding

```
<IfModule mod_speling.c>
CheckSpelling On
CheckCaseOnly On
</IfModule>
```

and now I am not getting internal server error ,but I am getting

> "file not found error"

www.myurl.com/mypages/page1.php  -->working fine.
 but
www.myurl.com/mypages/Page1.php  --> "file not found error"

Answer (score 0):

If you can load the mod_speling module. use this:

```
RewriteEngine On
AllowOverride All
CheckSpelling on
```

Otherwise; if you can't (you don't have control of it) force lowercase URLs with mod_rewrite (like you wrote on your question)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteMap  lc int:tolower
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
RewriteRule (.*) ${lc:$1} [R=301,L]
```

Since your .htaccess was inside a folder and now is in the document root (public_html) try to add your rewrite. Maybe it was just an issue because, it wasn't in the document root.

Comment: I tried adding CheckSpelling on  .but I am still getting the same internal server error

Comment: First of all, can you please, move the `.htaccess` to `public_html` and check the page. If you get the same error, remove content from `.htaccess` and check the page again. If the error still... you have an error on you page

Comment: I moved the .htaccess to public_html and I can see same internal server error . Then I removed the .htaccess  and I am getting error only if the case is not  matching.  www.myurl.com/mypages/page1.php -->working fine. but www.myurl.com/mypages/Page1.php --> >'file not found error'

Comment: Please don't provide "code only" answers. Please add explanation and dependencies.

Comment: I know what is going on. Based on this article Godaddy doesn't load the mod_spelling module. http://ionipti.blogspot.com/2009/11/godaddycom-linux-hosting-and-converting.html Therefore, you will have to force lowercase URLs with mod_rewrite. I will Update my answer

Comment: @robert Cool, I am glad that you fixed the issue. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue ,I changed all my file names to lowercase ,and added the following to .htaccess . (as suggested [here](http://ionipti.blogspot.com/2009/11/godaddycom-linux-hosting-and-converting.html) )

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !([A-Z]+)
RewriteRule .* - [S=27]
RewriteRule ^(.*)A(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1a$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)B(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1b$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)C(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1c$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)D(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1d$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)E(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1e$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)F(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1f$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)G(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1g$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)H(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1h$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)I(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1i$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)J(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1j$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)K(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1k$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)L(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1l$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)M(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1m$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)N(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1n$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)O(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1o$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)P(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1p$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)Q(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1q$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)R(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1r$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)S(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1s$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)T(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1t$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)U(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1u$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)V(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1v$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)W(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1w$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)X(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1x$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)Y(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1y$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)Z(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1z$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Now I don't see any errors and it accepts the requests irrespective of the case.